# Scroll bar not working in Visual Studio Code sometimes after closing MS Edge

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge

I am having this weird issue since I installed the latest version of VSCode for linux. Whenever a Microsoft Edge (dev) and a vscode window is open, and then I close the edge tab, scroll bar just stops working in vscode.

[Link to gif showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HBWD.gif) 
You can see the cursor disappears as well when I click the scroll bar after closing edge, while normally when scrolling, the cursor stays in its location.

If I then open a Firefox or Google Chrome tab, this problem suddenly disappears. I can then close all browsers without any problem, and the issue happens again only after I restart vscode.

Even more weird is that when I right click the edge browser's icon from task bar, and click Close from there (instead of opening the edge tab, clicking the cross button on top right), this issue happens only sometimes. This is very irritating to me as I usually use edge for my browsing tasks daily, and I don't know if this is an OS specific issue or what. Also I disabled all extensions in vscode, so they can't be causing the problem.

OS: Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 
VSCode version: 1.56.2 (Installed from .deb file at official site) 
Microsoft edge dev version: 92.0.884.2

Comment: You just need to update you VSCode settings to match the desired result. If you multiply by 0 all scroll events directions, that will mean that you will have 0 movements in offsets. That is why is should be defaulted to 1 (issue). Fix is easy to apply, no need to reinstall everything

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it in `settings.json` as well as `.workspace` file.

You need to set `mouseWheelScrollSensitivity` to 1 like that:

```json
  "editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 1,
  "terminal.integrated.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 1,
  "workbench.list.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 1,
```

Answer (score -3):

reinstall VSCdoe or reinstall Kubuntu.

Comment: Hello Veer, this should be supposed in comments as it is not a specific answer for this question.

Comment: Cannot reinstall my OS right now, I did reinstall vscode but still the issue happened for a couple of days.. suddenly right now its working fine, but I am not sure if it will happen again, and why it happened in the first place.